# Form doesn't reset with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to reset a form, but it doesn't clear out the previous selections. So when I refresh the page and submit it remembers the old values and submits them. Even if I haven't made any selections on the form. This is the code:

```
<script>
 $(function(){ 
   $("#eventForm")[0].reset();
   });
</script>
```

Thanks

EDIT: The form

```
<form id="eventForm">            
     <select name="eventer" id="abc">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select  Event</option>
        <option value="USA">US</option>
        <option value="UK">UK/option>
        <option value="Fr">France</option>
     </select>

    <input type="submit" id="open" onclick="heading()" value="Start" />
    <input type="button" id="close" onclick="closeAnalysis()" value="Stop"/>
```

I tried clearing them like this, but no success:

```
$(document).ready(
   function(){
   $("#close").click(
    function(){
     var values = [];
     var selected = $("select").each(
      function(){
      values.push( $(this).val());
      });
    this.form.reset();
    for (i=0;i<selected.length;i++)
    $(selected[i]).val(values[i]);
  });
  }
 );
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002957/jquery-form-reset-exclude-select-box

Comment: Could be browser-specific, what did you test it with?

Comment: @user94628: Ignore my answer, I answered quickly while suffering a sinus infection and my answer isn't even close to accurate or helpful.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: Ok no problems.

Comment: .reset() will not necessarily clear the fields, it will reset them to the values that are provided with the `value="..."` attribute.

Comment: Ok, in my form there are two select tags each with several option tags. The selected option tag for both has a value="" and disabled="disabled"

Comment: Does your form just post back to the same page, where you then clear the values? If so, refreshing the page will just post the old data again. Are you getting the browser warning?

Comment: Can you post the form HTML (as rendered when the `reset` is called), the expected outcome, and the actual outcome?

Comment: What's the point of selecting element at index 0 when calling $("#eventForm")[0].reset(); ? Shouldn't it be $("#eventForm").reset(); ?

Comment: I've included the form data

Comment: nevermind.. some specific jquery stuff I guess.. but you can do document.getElementById("eventForm").reset();

Comment: @Walialu Thanks I tried document.getElementById("eventForm").reset(); But doesnt work either

Answer (score 1):

[reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/form.reset) returns the fields to the initial values set when the page is loaded. It will not remove the text. If you want to remove the text, you are going to have to loop through the elements and clear them.

Comment: Wow, it's taken me ages to get my head round this!