# Clear the form once form submitted

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)

Once the form submitted, response from another page is printed to #GameStorySys. But values entered to the form still stays there. Is it possible for the form values to disappear (but the form should still stay) once the form submitted?

```
$("[name='GameStoryForm']").click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
                data: $("#GameStoryForm").serialize(),
                url: "content/commentary/index.cs.asp?Process=EditLiveCommentaryStory&CommentaryID=<%=Request.QueryString("CommentaryID")%>", 
                success: function(output) { 
                $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
            },
                error: function(output) {
                $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
                }
        }); 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can clear it manually, for example:

```
$("[name='GameStoryForm']").click(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#GameStoryForm").serialize(),
    url: "content/commentary/index.cs.asp?Process=EditLiveCommentaryStory&CommentaryID=<%=Request.QueryString("CommentaryID")%>", 
    success: function(output) { 
      $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
      $("#GameStoryForm").get(0).reset();
      //or manually:
      // $("#GameStoryForm :input").not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
      //                           .val('').removeAttr('checked selected');
    },
    error: function(output) {
      $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Very nice with the additional removeAttr call after val.

Comment: $("#GameStoryForm").get(0).reset(); should do it. I did not understand how exactly manual version would work. Once the form is submitted would user need to click reset button?

Comment: @zurna - by "manual" I just mean just programmatically clearing the inputs instead of using the form's `.reset()` functionality.  It's just a bit more explicit so you can see exactly what's going on...or leave out and not clear any elements you don't want to reset.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById(yourFormId).onsubmit = new Function(){this.reset();}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the reset in response function for AJAX query, it won't be made before the request returns. If you reset the form in the onsubmit() event handler (as suggested here) then it either won't be resetted at all (since you send the AJAX request in click() handler, not submit() handler).

What you need to do is perform the reset after issuing the AJAX request - that is, after calling $.ajax() - but not in its callback function called when request returns:

```
$("[name='GameStoryForm']").click(function() { 
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#GameStoryForm").serialize(),
    url: "content/commentary/index.cs.asp?Process=EditLiveCommentaryStory&CommentaryID=<%=Request.QueryString("CommentaryID")%>", 
    success: function(output) { 
      $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
    },
    error: function(output) {
      $('#GameStorySys').html(output);
    }
  });

  $("#GameStoryForm").get(0).reset();
});
```