# How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried `$("#client.frm").reset();` but it is not working.So how to reset form via jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery

Comment: Note: Clear and Reset are two different things. Reset (`.reset()`) will put the values back to the original values in the HTML. For this, see Nick Craver's solution below. "Clear" typically means to set the values back to blank / unchecked / unselected; see MahmoudS solution.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

[`form.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) is a DOM element method (not one on the jQuery object), so you need:

```
$("#client.frm")[0].reset();
//faster version:
$("#client")[0].reset();
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("client").reset();
```

Note: reset() function does not work if form contains any field with attribute:

```
name='reset'
```

Comment: My brain just expanded, thanks: "A jQuery object is an array-like wrapper around one or more DOM elements. To get a reference to the actual DOM elements (instead of the jQuery object), you have two options. The first (and fastest) method is to use array notation:
 $( "#foo" )[ 0 ]; // Equivalent to document.getElementById( "foo" )
The second method is to use the .get() function:
$( "#foo" ).get( 0 ); // Identical to above, only slower." http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Comment: I get next error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).reset is not a function[Learn More]. I use FormValidate plugin for form. its resetForm does not reset form too =( Any suggestions?

Comment: Eugen, here's where, much like Indiana Jones and The Last Crusade, you must take a leap of faith. If you call document.getElementById('myform').reset() it will actually clear the form even though that method seems to not exist. Typical M$ obfuscation.

Answer (score 50):

You can simply do:

`$("#client.frm").trigger('reset')`

Answer (score 27):

**Pure JS solution** is as follows:

```
function clearForm(myFormElement) {

  var elements = myFormElement.elements;

  myFormElement.reset();

  for(i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

  field_type = elements[i].type.toLowerCase();

  switch(field_type) {

    case "text":
    case "password":
    case "textarea":
          case "hidden":

      elements[i].value = "";
      break;

    case "radio":
    case "checkbox":
        if (elements[i].checked) {
          elements[i].checked = false;
      }
      break;

    case "select-one":
    case "select-multi":
                elements[i].selectedIndex = -1;
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is jQuery plugin solution that should be roughly equivalent. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24496012/1766230 (I used your `selectedIndex = -1` trick.)

Comment: This solution does not work now (in 2016). When form has default values for text, password and textarea inputs, you should use elements[i].defaultValue="" instead of elements[i].value="".

Comment: ```var field_type = elements[i].type.toLowerCase();```

Comment: @Andrew: It depends on what you want. If you just want to reset the form to the `defaultValue`s, you could just call `reset()` on the form object. The code here is to _clear_ the form, rather than reset it.

Comment: Nice function. I just had to add the type "number" to the first case.

Comment: The code has two operations: reset the form and truncate the fields?

Answer (score 9):

Note, function `form.reset()` will not work if some input tag in the form have attribute `name='reset'`

Comment: I couldn't for the life of me work out why it wouldn't work. Then the button I was using to reset had `id="reset"` changed to `id="rst"` and all is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

The `.reset()` method does not clear the default values and checkbox field and there are many more issues.

In order to completely reset check the below link -

http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.htm

Answer (score 5):

Clear the form as follows

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

You can simply clear the form elements within the group. by using this `forms[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use JavaScript function `reset()`:

```
document.forms["frm_id"].reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myform")[0].reset.click();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
$('[element]').trigger('reset')
```

Answer (score 1):

trigger form reset, remove checked + selected attributes (triggering reset doesn't remove attributes) and empty input values

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[data-reset-form]', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('form.my-form').trigger('reset')
   $('form.my-form').find('[checked]').removeAttr('checked')
   $('form.my-form').find('[selected]').removeAttr('selected')
   $('form.my-form').find('input').val('');
 })
```

Answer (score -4):

You can clear the whole form using onclick function.Here is the code for it.

```
 <button type="reset" value="reset" type="reset" class="btnreset" onclick="window.location.reload()">Reset</button>
```

window.location.reload() function will refresh your page and all data will clear.