# How do I clear the JQuery Mobile list search filter?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a JQuery Mobile (1.0rc1) application that has a list view with a search filter implemented. It's similar to [this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/#/demos/1.0rc1/docs/lists/lists-search.html) sample.

Under certain conditions, I am dynamically loading additional items into the list with an ajax call. When this happens I want to clear anything entered in the search filter, otherwise I end up with a partially filtered list.

I've tried firing the clear button like this:

```
$('.ui-button-clear', $.mobile.activePage).click();
```

and clearing the form like this:

```
$("form > input", $.mobile.activePage).val('');
```

but neither worked. Can someone enlighten me to the proper way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to clear clear the searchfilter with

```
$('input[data-type="search"]').val("");
```

**Edit:** To update the list you will also have to trigger the "change"-event on the searchfilter:

```
$('input[data-type="search"]').trigger("keyup");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ge3Tv/53/)

Comment: Great, also works on bug on: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/selectmenu-custom-filter/ When i have multiple choices, custom filter popup disapeared after first seach, these two commands helped.

Answer (score 1):

if you talking about Jquery mobile listview, then you need this

```
$('#autocomplete li').click(function () {
                                    $('.ui-input-clear').trigger("click");
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
$("form")[0].reset();
```

The `[0]` points to the DOM element method. 
Also see [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)