# Why aren't my hidden fields being reset when I execute the reset method on a form element?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to reset my form having id `user_post`. This form contains hidden fields also.
I used this code to reset input form fields

```
$('#user_post').each(function(){
this.reset();
});
```

My form  given bellow

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"  id="user_post" action="/****/index.php/site/username" method="post">
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="tab-1" >
<textarea rows="3"  placeholder="Share what have been up to...." name="Userpost[usertxtpost]" id="Userpost_usertxtpost"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="tab-2" >
<textarea rows="1"  placeholder="Title...." name="Userpost[title]" id="Userpost_title"></textarea>
<input id="Userpost_image" type="hidden" value="" name="Userpost[image]" />
<input  tabindex="21"  name="Userpost[image]" id="Userpost_image" type="file" />   
<input name="Userpost[imagename]" id="Userpost_imagename" type="hidden" />
<textarea rows="3"  placeholder="about this image...." name="Userpost[coment]" id="Userpost_coment"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="tab-3" class="tab-pane row-fluid fade">
<input name="Userpost[video_title]" id="Userpost_video_title" type="hidden" />
<textarea rows="1"  placeholder="Copy and paste video url...." name="Userpost[video]" id="Userpost_video"></textarea>
<input name="Userpost[video_text]" id="Userpost_video_text" type="hidden" />
</div>
<div id="tab-4" >
<input rows="3"  placeholder="Share url...." name="Userpost[link]" id="Userpost_link" type="text" maxlength="200" />
<input name="Userpost[url_title]" id="Userpost_url_title" type="hidden" />
<input name="Userpost[url_text]" id="Userpost_url_text" type="hidden" />
<input name="Userpost[url_image]" id="Userpost_url_image" type="hidden" />
</div>
<input value="121" name="Userpost[user_id]" id="Userpost_user_id" type="hidden" />              
<button type="button" id="submitTimelinePosts">SUBMIT </button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@VolkanUlukut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21756249/662581) mentioned, form fields of type `hidden` are not affected by the `reset` action of a form element.

This behavior can be seen in [this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrv65/).

If you need to be able to reset your form's hidden fields to their initial state, you will first need to make a map in JavaScript of their initial values at page load, and then restore that state at the form reset event.

I implemented this functionality in vanilla JavaScript, as can be seen below:

```
;(function (undefined) {
    var i, k, form, element,
        formInfo = [];

    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        form = document.forms[i];

        formInfo[i] = {};

        for (j = 0; j < form.elements.length; j++) {
            element = form.elements[j];

            if (!element || element.type !== 'hidden')
                continue;

            formInfo[i][j] = element.value;
        }

        form.addEventListener('reset', onFormReset);
    }

    function onFormReset(e) {
        var i, k;
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
            if (document.forms[i] === this) {
                for (k in formInfo[i]) {
                    this.elements[k].value = formInfo[i][k];
                }
            }   
        }
    }
})();
```

See a [demonstration at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yrv65/1/).

***Warning*** This script will not work properly if you are dynamically adding forms to the page.

***Warning*** This script was written to only work with `addEventListener`. If you need better browser support, use jQuery event binding, or modify the function to also use `attachEvent`.

Another method would be to store the initial state of the hidden element in a `data-*` attribute, then on reset, set the hidden fields to that value.

Here's a [demonstration of this method](http://jsfiddle.net/4dApd/).

```
;(function (undefined) {
    var i, j, form, element;

    var onFormReset = function (e) {
        var i, defaultValue;

        for (i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
            element = this.elements[i];

            if (element.type !== 'hidden')
                continue;

            this.elements[i].value = element.getAttribute('data-default');
        }
    };

    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        form = document.forms[i];

        for (j = 0; j < form.elements.length; j++) {
            element = form.elements[j];

            if (element.type !== 'hidden')
                continue;

            element.setAttribute('data-default', element.value);
        }

        form.addEventListener('reset', onFormReset);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 6):

it is unfortunately not possible to reset hidden fields.
but you can put `style='display: none'` on the text fields rather than making them hidden input fields. this way reset will work on them too.

Answer (score 0):

That is up to the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-49531485

In order to "hide" fields they way no want (i.e. being able to reset it) use css (`display:none`) on the field.

Answer (score 0):

.reset() belongs to the form not the fields so a beter way to do it would be

```
$("#resetButton").click(function(){
    $("#myForm")[0].reset();
});
```

[How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

or you can manually empty that field

```
$("#myHiddenField").val("");
```

but why would you want to reset a hidden field ?

Comment: Maybe he has changed the value of the hidden field based on interaction with other form elements?

Comment: yep i think so too ! maybe a colorpicker or calendar for example

Comment: Your first bit of code there doesn't do anything that the OP's code isn't already doing. The second part of your answer is a *solution*, though, it doesn't respect the original value of the hidden field.

Comment: I just noticed your first statement. In the OP's code, `#user_post` is his form. He's not calling `reset()` on each field. He's calling `reset()` on the form. `each()` is iterating the collection of jQuery elements selected by the jQuery selector `'#user_post'`, which is only a single element of type `form`.

Comment: i guess you are right. in order to reset a field to it's original value you would have to have stored that somewhere from the beginning like a data- attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="reset" id="reset_btn" value="Reset" />

$('#reset_btn').click(function(){
   $('#your_form')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: A) You didn't explain anything in your answer. B) Your answer is no different than the code in the original answer, except, instead of iterating with `$.each`, you simply reference the first node from the jQuery collection, and call `reset()` on it. That performs the same function.