# how to reset the whole form using jquery javascript..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a script to send email via Ajax php
code is working well but i also want to reset form after send email here is my jquery code

```
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#slider-submit').click(function(){
    $('#success').text('Sending...');

$.post("send.php", $("#slider-form").serialize(),  function(response) {   
 $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');


});
return false;
$('#slider-submit')[0].reset();

});

});
</script>
```

please tell me how is it possible i also used reset method but not working at all

Comment: $("#slider-submit").find('input:text, input:hidden, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: Can you show your form? One thing is you are calling reset after return false

Comment: Your reset line (`$('#slider-submit')[0].reset();`) is after the return statement, so it is not called. Append it to the ajax success function.

Comment: Add $('#slider-submit')[0].reset();  in sucess not after return false $('#success').html(response);
 //$('#success').hide('slow');
$('#slider-submit')[0].reset(); 

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reset line (`$('#slider-submit')[0].reset();`) is after the return statement, so it is not called. Append it to the ajax success function (assuming that the form id is ´slider-submit´).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider-submit').click(function(){
        $('#success').text('Sending...');

        $.post("send.php", $("#slider-form").serialize(),  function(response) {   
            $('#success').html(response);
            //$('#success').hide('slow');

            $('#slider-submit')[0].reset();
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are almost near to your goal, you just need to change the order of your statements (first reset the form, and then return false) in your script, that is as follows.

change

```
return false;
$('#slider-submit')[0].reset();
```

to

```
$('#slider-submit')[0].reset();
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods, one possible is to trigger the reset event.

Assuming that your form id is ´slider-submit´

```
$('#slider-submit').trigger('reset');
```

Answer (score 0):

In a normal scenario after posting ajax call using jquery.

```
$('#MyFormId').reset()

or

$( '#MyFormId' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});

Hopefully it should work.
```