# how do i empty the field

Tags: php, jquery

I use this code to submit a form

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#blogform');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
</script>

    <form id="blogform" action="/my_url" method="post">
        ...
    </form>
```

My problem is that if the submission is successful I want to be able to empty the form field.

Comment: In the form tag, the id is myform but in the jquery code it's blogform. It must be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I have corrected that.

Comment: In the success() part, instead of alert() change it to: `$('#blogform')[0].reset()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var frm = $('#blogform');` must be `var frm = $('#myform');` according to the form sample you provide in the question. And in order to reset your form, Use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript) before alert(data):

```
$('#myform').trigger("reset");
```

or

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

In your php code you can check whether the submission is successful or not and process that data the jquery like below:

```
if(data){
  $('#myform')[0].reset();
  alert(data);
}else{
 return false;
}
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript  [reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) method.

Comment: You should add a small example to boost the quality of your answer.