# Why '$("#form")[0].reset();' works and '$("#form").reset();' not?

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

I am using form reset method as below in my web pages

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

But when I use it like the below

```
$("#form").reset();
```

It is giving me error.

**Why the first method is working and the later is not?**

My page is working perfectly. But I would like the reason behind it. The solution is everywhere. But none of them describing the reason behind it.

**Note:** I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript) and it shows so much answers. Nothing clearly defines the reason.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: Because `reset` is not part of the jQuery API but the native API and you access the native element using `[0]`.

Comment: $("#form")[0] is the index position of your element's in form's DOM object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simple reason is it is for forcefully working a `javascript` function using `Jquery`

`.reset()` is not a Jquery native function. It is a `Javascript` function and we are forcefully using it inside `Jquery`

Answer (score 6):

The jQuery selector method can return more than one element, so the behaviour is to return an array for consistency's sake. This array is a wrapper for other jQuery methods that can operate on that selection, but manipulating the classic DOM functions requires working on a specific element.

You can do that like you have, with `[0]` to pull out the first, or you can iterate over them:

```
$('#form').each(function() { this.reset() });
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the `reset()` method is a member of the HTML form element:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset

And not a method offered by a jQuery object, which is a collection of 0 or more matching elements for your selector (`#form`)