# How can I clear form when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code like this :

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-image', function(e) {
    $(this).find('#form-add').trigger('reset');
    // $(this).find('#form-add').clearForm();
    // $('#form-add').clearForm();
    // $('#form-add').val("");
    // ...
});
```

If button clicked, I want the form clear

I try like that, but it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try simply $('#form-add').trigger('reset'), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing an entire form with Javascript or JQuery, it's recommended that you
 explicitly clear each of your elements.

For example, clearing all text inputs:

```
$('#txtbox1').val('');
$('#txtbox2').val('');
etc. etc.
```

Another less recommended alternative is to use `reset()`:

```
$('#myForm')[0].reset();
```

But this does not 100% guarantee clearing all elements within, since some of the elements may not be scoped within your form.

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486251/why-image-not-display-in-modal-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Let us suppose you have a button with class clearAll, call the below jquery function which will clear all the textfields and textarea at once...easier and simple...customize however you want...

```
$(".clearAll").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reset a form, is almost the same as clean.

Pure JS:

```
document.getElementById('THE-FORM-ID').reset();
```

DEMO: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset

Answer (score 0):

Try with `empty()` function jquery

```
$('body').on('click', '#add-image', function(e) {
    $(this).find('#form-add').trigger('reset');
     $(this).find('#form-add').find('input,textarea').empty()
});
```

Comment: I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486251/why-image-not-display-in-modal-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can clean all the text fides that undet that `form` like that :

```
$("#clean").click(function() {
    $(this)
    .closest('form')
    .find("input[type=text],textarea")
    .val('');
});
```