# Clear File upload value based on Radio button

Tags: jquery

When click on a radio button based on the buttons current value the value of a file upolad is needed to be clear and new value is needed to upload on it,how it is possible by using jquery on click or on change function

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: $("#fileInput").replaceWith($("#fileInput").val('').clone(true));

Comment: I like to use Jquery so,can you please suggest a solution using Jquery

Answer (score 0):

clear using javascript

```
 document.getElementById("yourfileid").value = null;
```