# how to insert the button back after the click of a click that makes a search?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

Hello I created a simple application that allows me to do a database search. I created an html page with functions in javascript. This is what shows my index.html

```html
<hmtl>
<body onload="initialize()">
        <h1>Choose your route:</h1> 
        <form action="/find" method="POST" autocomplete="on">
          <td><input type="text" name="mypos" placeholder="Your Position" size="20" /></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="yourpos" placeholder="Destination" size="20" /></td>
          <td><button type="submit">Search</button></td>
          <button type="Reset" value="Reset">Reset</button> 
       <div id="map_canvas" style="1500px; 1000px"></div>
         </body>
        </html>
```

After inserting the coordinates in the changes and then searching, my output will be a separate line where I can print to the screen if the route exists or not ie: Route not found or Route found.
My problem is to insert a button to go back to this point in the search so as to go back to the start page or index.html. The problem is that I only have one html page (index.html) so any command can only insert it in the search page and not in the results page (the results page is just a printed string is not another html page). This page also interacts with flask. I hope I was clear. Thank you very much for the attention.

Comment: Why there are two opening body tags and no closing form-tag?

Comment: What about a simple `<a href="some link">`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: The two are two body I was wrong to transcribe the code but that is not the problem. alexP.

Comment: with a simple command not work. Snackoverflow

Comment: I saw the question you asked me, but it has nothing to do with anything. I'm sorry. Serge K.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understand, what you have is `index.html` doing a postback, and the response of that postback renderizes a different page with the result of the insertion. And it's that result page from where you want to back to `index.html`. Well, you have two options:

**1.** In the result page, create a button like this:

```html
<button class="backbutton">Back</button>

<script>
    // Somewhere in your initialization code:
    const backbutton = document.querySelector('.backbutton');
    backbutton.addEventListener('click', function(){
        window.history.back();
    });
</script>
```

That gives you some flexibility because it doesn't depend on the route to your `index.html` page.

**2.** Simply include a link to your `index.html` page in your result page:

```html
<a href="index.html">Back to search form</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I modified the question.I tried your solution and it does not work because I think it's ok if I had two html pages connected while I own only one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the values from a form input after the form is submitted (and cleared), you need to have memorized the value somewhere beforehand. One way to do this is to add (to the input) a listener for the `blur` event (which happens when the input loses the focus, implying that the user is done editing the input).

In the listener function, you can store the value in a javascript variable for later, like

```
const firstMyPosInput = document.getElementsByName("myPos")[0];
let myPosValue = firstMyPosInput.value;
```

Now you can add a new button element (like `<button id="myBtn">Try again</button>` and give it a click listener that sets the input's value back to what it was before like `firstMyPosInput.value = myPosValue`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I modified the question maybe I explained the problem badly.