# After ajax execution firefox show all form fields as errors

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a contact form in a modal.

I submit the form using Ajax, and show a message depending on results, above the form.

The problem is, that when the results are returned from the Ajax, the browser(Firefox) marks all fields as errors. I want the browser not to that.

For ajax I'm using pure javascript:

```
function sendAjax(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var xhr, form;
        form = event.target;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                setResponseMessage(form, JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).message);
                resetForm(form);
......

// this function cleans the fields after submit.
function resetForm(form) {
        for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
                if (form.elements[i].type !== 'submit' || form.elements[i].name === DOMStrings.csrf) {
            form.elements[i].value = '';
        }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

===================

I don't use `form.reset()` because I have a hidden field that I don't want to clean.

Also, the issue is not related with cleaning the fields, the issue is that after submitting, and corect Ajax transimission,  **Firefox automatically, make the form fields as invalid based on HTML attributes**, add a red shadow.

I just want Firefox, to show the form as it is. There is no third-party or other code validation involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: are you validating your form using HTML `required` ?

Comment: @AbderrahimSoubaiElidrissi yes I use html attributes

Comment: @demo the issue is not with clearing fields, please see updated question

Comment: maybe set `value` to null can help, instead of empty string...