# jQuery: How to make a clear button?

Tags: jquery, button

I have a search field, and I need a clear button.

I currently have the button, but I don't know how to do it,

I have 6 textfields, 2 comboboxes, and 2 multiple select lists

How do I clear all of them in one clear function??
I know the HTML way, but I am using Grails and the type="reset" does not work.
That's why I want a jQuery way of deleting textboxes' values, leaving the combobox in the first index, and clear all options from the multiple select list.

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: http://www.codigomanso.com/en/2008/12/resetear-un-formulario-con-jquery/

Comment: I for one wonder why people have clear buttons, they always seem useless to me.

Comment: Ummm... To make your form neat and organized? o_O

Comment: I have to agree with Winston here, and then you fill in 10 fields and by accident press the clear button just to redo it. meh

Comment: Yeah nobody wants a clear button.  Nobody wants any button!  That's why Google came out with Google Instant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify the code below to suit your needs. It's stolen from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery) anyway.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/syen81/EPcnR/)

```
$(':input','#myform')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');

<form id='myform'>
    <input type='text' value='test' />
    <select id='single'>
        <option>One</option>
        <option selected="true">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="true" size="5" id='multiple'>
        <option>One</option>
        <option selected="true">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='reset' value='reset' />
</form>
```

*EDIT (To clear multiple select):*

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
    $(':input','#myform')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');

    $("#myform #multiple").empty();
});​
```

[**jsfiddle v2**](http://jsfiddle.net/syen81/EPcnR/2/)

Comment: This is the way to go no doubt. +1

Comment: Ok, almost perfect. I need to leave the multiple select empty. With no options in it.

Comment: Each jQuery function that returns a jQuery collection (like val(), not(), removeAttr()) has the .each() built in, e.g. http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L18

Comment: Here is the jQuery `$('#reset').click(function(){
    $(':input','#myform')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
    $("#myform #list").empty();
});`

Comment: nice.. I have updated the JQuery to clear multiple selection box as well.

Comment: Just to mention, this will clear checkbox value, which probably is not desirable.

Answer (score 9):

If you have a form just add a input with type `reset`

```
<input type="reset" value="Clear the Form" />
```

If you can't use this, then save the default values using `.data` and retrieve them on you reset the form.

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUGmL/)**

```
$("#container :text").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.data("default", $this.val());
});

$("#container select option").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.data("default", $this.is(":selected"));
});

$("#container :button").click(function() {
    $("#container :text").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.val($this.data("default"));
    });

  $("#container select option").each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.attr("selected", $this.data("default"));
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="text" value="default" />
    <select>
        <option>Op1</option>
        <option selected="true">Op2</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="true" size="5">
        <option>Op1</option>
        <option selected="true">Op2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" value="reset" />
</div>
```

---

To clear all inputs and remove all options on `select` elements its more simple, [see this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MUGmL/1/) (same html).

```
$("#container :button").click(function() {
    $("#container :text").val("");

    $("#container select").empty();
});
```

Comment: @fgualda87: What about now? :P

Comment: LOL, much better, but for the multiple select list, I want it to be blank, like remove all the options that it has. Like since is a search field, I add things to the list, and with the clear button it should erase all of them. Now, for demonstration purposes I only have to values, maybe if I erase them and leave it like that from the beginning it'll work?? Thanks

Comment: To erase an input field just set val to empty: `val("")`. And to remove all options call `empty`. `$("#container select").empty();`

Answer (score 1):

Use **Lee Sy En's**  solution that he found on SO.
It's much better and takes care of everything.

```
$('#myClearButton').click(function() {
  $('#myTextBox').val('');

  $('#myComboBox').val('0'); // set to default value as an example i use 0 
});
```

Comment: What about the combo box? And the multiple select list??