# how to abort all changes on screen by hit of Cancel button?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button

What should I implement for Cancel button, so that when user presses it, screen returns to the  previous values for all editable fields?

I have a button:

```
<button type="submit" id="btnCancel" name="Command" value="Cancel">
  Cancel
</button>
```

and method in controller that handles POST events for submit type. Not sure whether I should handle abort of changes via this way; or have some jQuery to handle this in the view. Could you please advise?

Comment: **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/wLTTV/ `:))` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925781/jquery-how-to-make-a-clear-button

Comment: I doubt deleting the form entirely is what he wants.

Comment: Shouldn't a `<input type="reset">` do exactly this?

Comment: +1 to you as well @numbers1311407 and @onetrickpony. `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would want to change your button like this...

`<button type="reset" id="btnCancel" name="Command" value="Cancel">
      Cancel
    </button>`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bFcce/)**