# Re-populate drop down list options, how to clear options list and then re-populate?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Re-populate drop down list options, how to clear options list and then re-populate?

When a event fires, I need to wipe out the current contents of the drop down list #users, and then re-populate it via ajax.

My ajax call is returning the HTML for the options like:

```
<option name=blah1>text1</option>
<option name=blah2>text2</option>
<option name=blah3>text3</option>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just change the `html` of the `select` element using the data returned from your ajax call

```
$("#users").html(data);
```

so it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: : function(data) {
        $("#users").html(data);
    }
    dataType: "HTML"
});
```

Answer (score 24):

you can use the below

```
$('#mySelect').empty()
```

and then rebind the new data.

Comment: @blankman , #myselect is equivalent to #users. i just gave that code to let you empty the results, yes .html will append the data..

Answer (score 2):

```
function(ajaxResult) {
   $('#users').html(""); //clear old options
   $('#users').html(ajaxResult);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the call back of your AJAX call, just clear out the contents of your select element and re-add those returned by the AJAX call.

```
function(ajaxResult) {
   $('#users').html(ajaxResult);
}
```