# Loading list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: asp.net, listview, jquery-mobile

I have am using JQuery Mobile in asp.net web form and on button click I want to load the list. In code behind I am getting the list is this way

```
List<Reportee> associates = new List<Reportee>();
associates = DALLayer.GetReporteeForEmployee(EmployeeId);
```

Here, associate is a class which has two property [reporteeName and reporteeId].

How can I show all the reportee Name in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

print a `<ul>` tag

for each associate:

- print `<li>`
- print the text you want
- print `</li>`

when foreach ends print `</ul>`

I have no idea why you asked...

What does it have to do with jquery mobile? O, I know! Instead of `<ul>` print `<ul data-role="listview">`

Comment: I have done the same in the aspx page but it is expecting to load the list on the page load, I want the same at the button click event which means I have to inititate the list creation after button click, how can I do so ?

Comment: That's done with AJAX. If you don't want to make it another page or dialog, then you have to write some javascript on your own. Loading a list via AJAX with help of jQuery is an old subject, you'll find it everywhere

Comment: Like this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136092/re-populate-drop-down-list-options-how-to-clear-options-list-and-then-re-populat