# How would I reset the value of this form with JQuery?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery, reset

I want to reset the value of this form which sends an AJAX request to the server:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/showable_videos" class="new_showable_video" id="new_showable_video" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="+hPWXwRBfAfz5lCKJRM3QouBzsYuje+wgGKb2OAH7Z4="></div>
    <input id="video_id_field" name="showable_video[video_id]" type="hidden" value="506">
    <input class="showable_field ui-autocomplete-input" id="showable_video_profile" name="showable_video[profile]" size="30" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
</form>
```

I tried `$('form#new_showable_video')[0].reset();` but it doesn't seem to work, possibly because a user selects an element from an autocomplete list, and upon selection the AJAX request is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here : [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery)