# How to clear textarea form in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, forms

How can I clear a form in HTML/JS without loading external libraries?

Here's what I've tried so far and how they fail:

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

This doesn't clear the form, only resets it to its original value.

```
form.getElementsByTagName('textarea').innerHTML = ''
```

This only clears the form if it has not been edited. If the form has been edited, it does nothing. Here's a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6bcs/) where these 2 have been combined, but if you edit the textarea and click clear, you can see it doesn't work ([source of JSfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6029442/4490400)).

Comment: Why don't you just replace `innerHTML` to `value` instead?

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: How cruel this world is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `text[i].value` instead of `text[i].innerHTML`:

```js
function resetForm(form) {
    // clearing inputs
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
        switch (inputs[i].type) {
            case 'hidden':
            case 'text':
                inputs[i].value = '';
                break;
            case 'radio':
            case 'checkbox':
                inputs[i].checked = false;   
        }
    }
    
    // clearing selects
    var selects = form.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for (var i = 0; i<selects.length; i++)
        selects[i].selectedIndex = 0;
    
    // clearing textarea
    var text= form.getElementsByTagName('textarea');
    for (var i = 0; i<text.length; i++)
        text[i].value= '';
    
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form method='post' action='someaction.php' name='myform'>

<input type='text' name='text1' value="a value">
<input type='text' name='text2'>

<input type='checkbox' name="check1" checked>Check Me
<input type='radio' name="radio1" value="a" >
<input type='radio' name="radio1" value="b" checked>
<input type='radio' name="radio1" value="c">

<textarea rows="2" cols="20" name='textarea1'>
some text    
</textarea>

<select name='select1'>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<input type='reset' value='Reset' name='reset' onclick="return resetForm(this.form);">
<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit'>

</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following way I edited and it clears the textarea https://gist.github.com/anonymous/76b3c08a2d38ddafc15791501173a6b8

Comment: Link-only answers aren't considered valuable on SO.