# Clear PlaceHolder controls on client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, placeholder

Is it possible to clear all `asp:PlaceHolder` controls on client side using JavaScript?

Something like: `placeHolder.Controls.Clear()` - but this is on server side.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following jQuery code:

```
$("#placeHolder").html("");
```

Comment: PlaceHolder will create a simple DIV without any IDs, so don't think it will work

Comment: and also is not say here that is use jQuery, how ever this is the idea

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but works. Surround your PlaceHolder with another div:

```
<div id="masterDiv">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="placeHolder1" >
            Some stuff
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="Don't click!" />
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
 </div>
```

If you can use jQuery, then use the **empty** function or **html('')**

```
$('#masterDiv').empty();
```

Or

```
$('#masterDiv').html('');
```

If you must use JavaScript, then do same:

```
document.getElementById('masterDiv').innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can use JQUERY, I tried both solutions but it doesn't work. To make things clearer, I want to clear only the controls inside the asp:PlaceHolder. Based on your example:             <input type="text" /> 
            <input type="submit" value="Don't click!" />

Comment: Did you want to clear the contents of those controls or do you want to just clear the whole placeholder of any controls so that you are left with <div id="masterDiv"></div> (the latter does work)?

Comment: I want to clear the placeholder controls (the controls themselves, not just their content), but I don't want to remove the placeholder from the page. Exactly like - placeholder.controls.clear() function, but in client side.

Comment: This topic has many suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery

Comment: Thanks Andrei, but I don't want to clear textbox text, for example.. I want to remove the textbox itself from the place holder.

Comment: Placeholder typically creates a DIV, so you can run $('#masterDiv div').empty();  to remove controls from it.