# Reset form after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new with ajax and jquery.
i have used the following code to submit form data it working fine.

but i need to reset(clear form field) after submit form with all validation true.
where to write a code to clear a form.

**Html Form:**

```
<form action="#" name="formdata" id="replyform" method="post">
    <div class="pass-form">
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="row_label">
                Old Password
            </div>
            <span><input type="text" id="User_pass1" name="User_pass1"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="row_label">
                New Password:
            </div>
            <span><input id="User_pass2" name="User_pass2" type="password"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="row_label">
                Re-Enter New Password:
            </div>
            <span><input id="User_pass3" name="User_pass3" type="password"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-row">
            <div class="row_label">
                &nbsp;
            </div>
            <span>&nbsp;<button name="chpass" onclick="submitform();" class="button" type="button" value="Save">Save</button>
            <button name="chpr" type="reset" class="button" value="Reset">Reset</button></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript function:**

```
 function submitform() {
        var User_pass1 = document.getElementById("User_pass1").value.match("^\\S[0-9a-zA-Z.-]*$");
        var User_pass2 = document.getElementById("User_pass2").value.match("^\\S[0-9a-zA-Z.-]*$");
        var User_pass3 = document.getElementById("User_pass3").value.match("^\\S[0-9a-zA-Z.-]*$");
        //document.getElementById("User_pass1").value="";
        //document.getElementById("User_pass2").value="";
        //document.getElementById("User_pass3").value="";
        if (User_pass1 == null) {
            alert("password field Required.....!");
            return;
        } else if (User_pass2 == null) {
            alert(" New password  field Required.....!");
            return;
        } else if (User_pass3 == null) {
            alert("New password conformation field Required.....!");
            return;
        } else if (String(User_pass2) != String(User_pass3)) {
            alert("New password and  conformation not match....!");
            return;
        } else {
            var str = "User_pass1=" + User_pass1 + "&User_pass2=" + User_pass2;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: _baseurl + "/setting/",
                data: str,
                success: function (output) 
                {alert(output);}
            });
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also do not make the reset button too easy to hit by mistake. I can remember the days of filling out a large form and hitting reset by mistake and loosing a lot of time... I think that's why you hardly see reset buttons anymore.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum:i google and tried the solution same as 'Dipesh parmar' suggest me but it did not work.

Comment: `document.forms['replyform'].reset()` or even `User_pass1.form.reset()`.

Comment: BTW, the submit listener should be on the form, not the button, since forms can be submitted without clicking the button.

Comment: @RobG:your first option work.but can you tell me why $('#replyform').reset(); is not working.

Comment: Because jQuery doesn't have a `reset` method?

Answer (score 3):

You need to write in inside `success` callback.

```
success: function (output) 
{
  alert(output);
  $('#replyform').reset();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: _baseurl + "/setting/",
      data: str,
      success: function (output)  {
         alert(output);
         $('#replyform').find("input[type=text], input[type=password]").val("");
      }
 });
```

Also if you are using `jQuery` than you should use `$('#User_pass1').val()` in place of `document.getElementById("User_pass1").value`

Comment: Whether jQuery is being used or not, far simpler to put the listener on the form's submit handler, pass `this` and use `form.User_pass1.value`.

Comment: @Swap Try the above code. Read also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery

Comment: @RohanKumar:Thanks. but RobG answer work for me.see comment on my question.