# Using jquery how can I clear all the text boxes on a form if I click in one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to clear all the text boxes on a form if the user clicks on any one of them. Basically I have some fields from a db from which to search as rows in a table. Then there is a radio button for each row. I want to have it setup so that when the user clicks in a text box it all the other text boxes on the form must have their values set to ''.

So far this code works to clear the current text box:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.novalue').focus(function() {
            $(this).val("");
        });
    });
```

All my text boxes in the table has the class="novalue" property. I just cannot figure out how to make it clear all and not just the one.

Comment: possible duplicate of **[Clear form fields with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)**

Comment: try `$('.novalue').val('')`

Comment: `$('.novalue').focus(function() {
            $('.novalue').val("");
        });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close. But you don't want to reset `$(this)`, but *all* input fields of that class:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.novalue').focus(function() {
        $('.novalue').val("");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/V7j3b/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.novalue').focus(function () {
        $('.novalue').val("");
    });
});
```