# render some partial after destroy method. Rails, haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a problem with destroy method. My idea is re-render partial, but partial should to do the check `if @driving_informations.present?`. So when I click link "delete" page do nothing, and data is staying in the page, when I press F5 and page reload everything ok - data not exist!

This is my controller method

```
def destroy
    @driving_information.destroy
    @user = @driving_information.user
    @driving_informations = @user.driving_informations
    render '_list.html.haml', layout: false
end
```

and View

```
%h4= t("driving_information.driving_info")
-if @driving_informations.present?
  =render ("list")
  -if @user == current_user
    - @driving_informations.each do |driving_information|
      = link_to t('common.edit'), edit_driving_information_path(driving_information), remote: true, data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#ajax-modal" }
      = link_to t('common.delete'), driving_information_path(driving_information), method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: t('common.confirm') }
-else
  = link_to t('common.add'), new_driving_information_path, remote: true, data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#ajax-modal" } if @user == current_user
  %p= t('driving_information.not_exists') if @user != current_user

:javascript
  $(function(){
    $("table.driving-information .destroy-btn").on("ajax:success", function(event, data, status, xhr){
      $('#driving-information-block').html(data);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have `driving_information` (with underscore) in haml table (if i read it correctly, i don't know haml) but `driving-information` (with dash) in javascript, maybe that's why js is not being called?

Comment: no, js using just for flash message

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that in your AJAX for on success of the destroy, target the form using jQuery and clear it.  Assuming your form ID is `form`:

`#('#form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");`

Source: [Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)