# Advanced Custom Fields wrongly prefilled

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up a form with advanced custom fields on the frontend in order to allow posts being generated from the frontend.

The form works but every time I visit the page with the form the form is prefilled with values however in the custom field setup I have no default value specified.

here is the code I am using.

```
<?php acf_form_head();
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
    <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php the_post(); ?>

        <?php 

         $options = array(
            'post_id' => 'new',
            'field_groups' => array(36),
            'submit_value'  => 'Create Quote Request' , 
            'updated_message'  => 'Quote Created!' 

        );

        acf_form( $options ); ?>

    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change 'Create Quote Request' to **' '** because that's the text populating your text box... so removing it will stop populating it.

Comment: If You provide the answer please spend some time an write at least short comment with explanation.

Comment: Nope. 'Create Quote Request' is the value of the submit button not of the field. I have a number of fields and they all are prefilled not just a single one.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. When you right click in the browser to inspect element does it look like this
`<input type="text" id="textbox" value="TextBox Text">`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I couldn't figure out how to unset it properly, so I jQueried it. Hope this helps.

```
$(".reset").ready(function() {
    $('.acf-form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
});
```

Replace .acf-form with either your form id or  class

I altered to my needs from this:
[Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)