# reset form created dynamically with a template

Tags: jquery

When I click a button, I go search info on server (via ajax).

I takes this info and push it in a handlerbar template who are in a dialog.
When i close my dialog, I do:

```
$('#editForm').trigger("reset")
```

When I click on another element and the dialog open, I see previous value. It's like the reset it's not working correctly.

Don't know if I need to reset something on the template side.

I don't have any error.

Comment: Can you post more of your code?

Comment: see this:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6364313/203141