# Refresh html page on changing tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

I have problem in shifting from one tab to another in HTML. I have two tabs, #tab1 and #tab2. I have one form in each of the tabs. when I enter details in #tab1, come to #tab2 and again go back to #tab1, the data I entered is not getting refreshed. The old values are retained back. I want a refreshed form.

I tried reloading the page itself by giving -

```
window.reload(true);
```

Whwn I did this, the page is displaying and disappearing within a fraction of second.

And also, tried refreshing the form alone by giving -

```
$('#formID').reset();
```

Then, the tab itself is not working. I am not getting any exceptions here. I am using jquery for shifting tabs.

Can any one please help me out in tracing out this problem?

Comment: Can you post the respective code or a demo..?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

```
$("tabIdHere").click(function(){
  $('#formID')[0].reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ..

`$("tabIdHere").click(function() {
       $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], input[type=password],textarea").val("");
   });`

[Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery) check here too