# Reset all inputs of a form to default values without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, default-value

I want to reset all the values of my inputs that I have within a form (textboxs, selects, checkboxs, radiobuttons,...) like if I reload the web, but when I touch a button.

```
$("#button").click(function () {
     //Here the code that I need   
});
```

Comment: `$('#myForm').trigger("reset");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reset a form using JavaScript built-in `reset()` function:

```
$("#otra").click(function () {
    $("#yourFormId")[0].reset();
});
```

Working demo:

```js
$("#otra").click(function () {
  $("#yourFormId")[0].reset();
  return false; // prevent submitting
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="yourFormId">
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCB"/>
  <input type="text" name="myTB" value=""/>
  
  <button id="otra">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way

```
$('input, textarea').val('');
$('select').find('option').prop("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can reset the complete form using this code

```
$('#myForm').trigger("reset");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('form[name="myform"]')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

My page preserves fields during post back, reset() doesn't remove them.

This helped me:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery%20%22Duplicatw)

```
$(".reset").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");    
});
```

Other types can be added.