# Clear form elements after using browser's back button in MVC razor View

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Create View form in an MVC5 application and after creating a record I redirect to another view called Completed. If the user click back button of the web browser, the previous data retains and I cannot clear the form fields using the following methods below:

***View:***

```
document.getElementById("frmCreate").reset();
```

or

```
$('#frmCreate').trigger("reset");
```

or

```
$("#frmCreate")[0].reset();
```

I also tried to clear ModelState in the controller, but does not make any sense.

***Controller:***

```
//code omitted for brevity

db.Visitors.Add(visitor);
db.SaveChanges();

// This will clear whatever form items have been populated
ModelState.Clear();

return RedirectToAction("Completed");
```

Any idea except from the above in order to clear all of the form elements?

Comment: can you please post your html ... atleast to get the idea of form and input fields

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery) , may be useful to you

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar Sorry, I am out of office now, but I use Html.TexboxFor and similar razor components in the form.

Comment: AFAIK, elements bound for a model (TextBoxFor, DropDownListFor etc) will retain its value on postback until the model contents has cleared from the controller side. You can pass an empty model like `return View(new ViewModel())` when user pressing back button or use `RedirectToAction("url")` when handling postback request.

Comment: Could you please give an example to use the code instead of RedirectToAction("url")?

Comment: **$(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("")** worked for TexBoxes. But I also need to clear (select first child element) of Dropdownlists (DropDownListFor) and DateTimePickers. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following function in you script,

```
 $(window).load(function() {
         $('form').get(0).reset(); //clear form data on page load
     });
```

Comment: This actually didn't work for me. I ended up using this: `window.addEventListener('load', function () { document.querySelector('form.search-form').reset(); });` and avoiding jQuery altogether for this.