# Jquery clear/reset form that i fill

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

ex I have 2 form input and 1 select form, when I select A 1 of the form hide and  auto reset/clear.

basiclly i've done hide logic, but i can't reset it.

here's my code :

```
var employedTypeOption = $('#employedType-option');
employedTypeOption.on('change', function() {
  if (employedTypeOption.val() == 1) {
    $('#hourly-rate, #parttime-panel').show();
    $('#basic-salary').hide();
  } else if (employedTypeOption.val() == 0){
    $('#basic-salary').show();
    $('#hourly-rate, #parttime-panel').hide();
  }
});
```

any idea ?

Comment: what do you mean by reset?

Comment: have you tried $(selector).val("")?

Comment: @MidTwo clear all the form that i fill

Comment: @arsinawaz haven't

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear form fields with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the text fields and textareas inside your form and reset their values. Like the following.

```
var employedTypeOption = $('#employedType-option');
employedTypeOption.on('change', function() {
  if (employedTypeOption.val() == 1) {
    $('#hourly-rate, #parttime-panel').show();
    $('#basic-salary').hide();

    $('#yourFormID').find('input[type="text"], textarea').val("");

  } else if (employedTypeOption.val() == 0){
    $('#basic-salary').show();
    $('#hourly-rate, #parttime-panel').hide();

    $('#yourFormID').find('input[type="text"], textarea').val("");

  }
});
```

Comment: working, but even with empy form it still can be save ?
any i've add bootstrap validator notEmpty.

Comment: You can add required attribute to these fields, or you can use JQuery validator as well.

Comment: I've added field must be numeric, and tried jquery validator. any other solution ?