# Reset button not working in html (php)

Tags: php, html

I have placed my input type reset button inside form but its still not working.

```
<form method='post' action='process/update_news_action.php' >
<tr>
   <td colspan='2' class="col-md-4">Update News Content</td>
</tr>
<tr >
   <td colspan='2' class="col-md-8"><textarea name="news" id="text"><?php echo  $rows["news"] ;  ?></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="col-md-4"><input name='submit' type="submit" value='Publish' class="btn btn-success" /></td>
   <td class="col-md-4"><input name='reset' type="reset" value='Reset' class="btn btn-primary" /></td>
</tr>
</form>
```

I have also tried `<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>`

Comment: Not working *how*? Is it inside a form?

Comment: Place full code here

Comment: Paste your whole code or use SO snippet for better understanding.

Comment: If you use the reset button inside the <form>, it will work.

Comment: it won't work unless and until you use it in form tag. try to use it inside form tag

Comment: my input type rest is within form only..

Answer (score 27):

If you're expecting the reset button to empty out the form, that's not the way reset works. It will reset the form fields to *what they were when the page was loaded*. In this case, you have pre-filled content in your form, so clicking reset will simply undo any user changes since the page-load.

To reset all form fields to blank/nothing, you will need javascript. First get the form DOM object, then iterate over all the input types you want to reset, and set each `field.value = ''` (input text types / textarea), or modify attributes (for select, radio, checkbox etc.) to deselect and so on. Turn that into a function (there's probably a ready piece somewhere out there, I seem to have lost mine), and attach it to your reset button's `click` event -- or your form's `reset` event.

**Edit:** On a quick search, here's a basic example of [how to clear a form](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-reset-form.phtml) to empty values.

**Edit:** If you're not concerned over anything but text fields, here's a simple way to do this. We add a "reset" event listener to the form, and when it fires, all fields are set to empty string.

```
function setFormCleanReset(formId) {
    let formEl = document.querySelector(formId);
    
    // Add event listener for reset event
    formEl.addEventListener('reset', function(e) {
    
        // Iterate all non-hidden fields, set values to ''
        for(const fieldEl of formEl.querySelectorAll('input:not([type=hidden])')) {

            // @todo check input type and handle "select" etc.
            fieldEl.setAttribute('value', '');
        }
    });
}
// usage: setFormCleanReset('my_form_id');
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6364313/7794769) for how to clear a form to empty values.

Comment: Indeed this is an important clarification as to what 'reset' actually does -- that it puts them back to what they were when the page was loaded as opposed to clearing the values -- which a surprising number of other 'authoritative' web source have completed wrong!

Comment: So when I click on an Edit button on my page, it displays a modal form with pre-populated information. When I click the Reset button, and then click on the Add button on my page, the modal pops up with the pre-populated information from the previous Edit button. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Bobort there is no "Add" button in the HTML form spec. If you are using a particular javascript framework to generate or modify forms, you may want to write a new question detailing what you're trying to do and how. Otherwise, your browser may be pre-filling form fields, check your browser settings and/or turn `autocomplete="off"` for your form fields ([Moz reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion)).

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to insert `form` tag in your **html**. It should be work if you insert button code into `<form>..button code here..</form>`.Something like this:

```html
<form>
   <input type="text">
   <td class="col-md-4">
      <input name='reset' type="reset" value='Reset' class="btn btn-primary" />     
   </td>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place the `<input type="reset">` in a form like this,it will definitely work

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Tring Reset</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type="text"></input>
<input type=reset></input>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your reset button inside form. In following code I have taken one input box also an an example. I hope it helps.

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" />
     <table>
        <td class="col-md-4">
        <input name='reset' type="reset" value='Reset' class="btn btn-primary" /> 
        </td>
     </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try without echo anything inside **textarea**

try this

```
<form method='post' action='process/update_news_action.php' > 

                                                <tr>
                                                <td colspan='2' class="col-md-4">Update News Content</td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <tr >
                                                    <td colspan='2' class="col-md-8"><textarea name="news" id="text"></textarea></td>
                                                </tr>
                                                 <tr>
                                                    <td class="col-md-4"><input name='submit' type="submit" value='Publish' class="btn btn-success" />   </td> 
                                                <td class="col-md-4"><input name='reset' type="reset" value='Reset' class="btn btn-primary" />   </td> 
                                                </tr>

                                        </form>
```

I think reset button is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse Me! You are using default value in input attribute. Remove default value from it. Then type anything then click rest it will make your text box empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have a form submitting variables to another PHP file. In the second file, there is a button that leads back to the first file for eventual correction od submitted values. The values are retained in the form by $_POST. The "Reset" button works only when the form is used the first time (empty). After submitting and return from the second PHP file, the "Reset" doesn't do anything, no values are cleared. The button seems to be fully inactive.

```
<button title="<?php echo $lang['reset-button-hint']; ?>" alt="TOOLTIP 1" type="reset" name="reset"><?php echo $lang['reset-button']; ?></button>
```

Answer (score -1):

@Jaspreet Kaur You need to add form tag outside the table. Please check my previous comment for it.

Comment: form tag can be added anywhere,