# Want to auto refresh my form without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a `Ask Question` form by which client can ask any question to us. While client submit the form we will give him a thanks message for 5 seconds then hide the message and show again the `Ask Question` form in that div.

But while the from comes after successful message, form input values is still there. I want a fresh from without any input value like the form before submitting.

[image: Fill the form for asking a question]

[image: Give thanks message after successfully submitted]

[image: Auto new form comes after shown successful message for 5 seconds. But still the previous input values there]

**Here is my `ajax` code**

```
$.ajax({

            url:"{{ url('/ask_question_form') }}",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {_token :token, name : name, email : email, contact : contact, question : question},
            success:function(msg){

                // console.log(msg);

                $('.question-modal .textwidget').hide();

                trHTML = "";
                trHTML += "<div id='user-question' style='margin-top:50%; color:#0071BC'>";

                trHTML += "Thanks for your question. We will save your question for further query and give a feedback as soon as possible.";

                trHTML += "</div>";

                $('.question-modal').append(trHTML);

                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('.question-modal #user-question').remove();
                    $('.question-modal .textwidget').show();
                }, 5000);


            }
        });
```

Where `textwidget` is the class name of that `form`

Comment: post your code here!!

Comment: you can simply `form.reset()` it

Comment: @Manoj mind that typo

Comment: can you show your code here?

Comment: @Bhumi Shah0...add the code...please check

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)

Comment: @ Manoj...No it's not !!

Comment: @ArafatRahman , `I want a fresh from without any input value like the form before submitting.` what does it mean then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is-

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

use this code when your success message comes.

Comment: Ya...now it's done.....
Give an `id` into your `form`..
`$("#form_id")[0].reset();`

Comment: Ohh that's great :)

Answer (score 1):

After completing 5 seconds and when you hide the "success message" at that time you can reset your form

```
$("#formId").get(0).reset();
```

Here "***formId*** " id of your form.

Comment: Are you using jquery in your project ?

Comment: and you are using $(".formclass").get(0).reset(); or $(".formclass").[0].reset(); ?

Comment: or you can do 
document.getElementsByClassName("formclass").[0].reset()

Comment: Yes I use jquery in my project..But I tried with `jQuery(".formclass").get(0).reset();` too...still same error

Comment: brother if I use `document.getElementsByClassName("formclass").[0].reset()`.. the form is not submitted then

Comment: ....Thanks brother it's done..great effort from you. But another person give that answer before you. So I accept her answer. And give an up vote to your comment. Yours one is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Erase values of all fields once you successfully submit the form.

```
document.querySelector('get-your-field1').value = '';
document.querySelector('get-your-field2').value = '';
document.querySelector('get-your-field3').value = '';
document.querySelector('get-your-textarea').value = '';
```

Or you can use `form reset`.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  form.reset();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input />
  <input />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ...Is there any function in javascript that refresh the whole form fields?

Comment: @ArafatRahman, `$(form)[0].reset()` is the function you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to do a form reset function:

```js
function reset(){
    setTimeout(function(){    
      var form = document.getElementById('myForm');
      form.reset();
    }, 1000);
}
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function(){
  reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">

  <input value="" />
  <br />
  <input value="" />
  <br />
  <input value="" />
  <br />
  <input value="" />
  <br />

  <button id="btn" type="button">reset</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please note, that it seems that you are using some token along with the form.

This means, that if you reset the values, this token will still be there,
and maybe the server will not accept the next form submission, due the duplicate use of that token.

You will need to set a new token, when the server respond.