# the function written in javascript works after refresh the page in firefox, I really can not figure not why

Tags: javascript

I am now programming, using Jquery, to render the preview page before submitting a form. I fill in some of the fields and click the 'preview button' to preview. the result is not what i want, I think there are some bugs, but the strange thing is : when i refresh the page in firefox, which will keep the filled values, the result is exacty what i want now. can somebody tell what might be the problem or give me a clue to check that

Comment: Without more details (e.g.: code) nobody can help you. We haven't the second sight.

Comment: Perhaps providing some code or example of what you are trying to do might help people give better answers ....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could reset / remove the values from the form using jQuery -> [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery/680252#680252)