# clear file input field using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blank out a form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery)

I am using a jQuery function to clear all my form values.

```
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag == 'form')
      return $(':input',this).clearForm();
    if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
      this.value = '';
    else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
      this.checked = false;
    else if (tag == 'select')
      this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};
```

the problem with above function is it does not reset the file input field. is there anyway i could extend the function and make it to work with clearing file input field as well.

here is file input field HTML code i am using.

```
<section><label for="productimg">Picture<br></label>
    <div><input type="file" id="productimg" name="productimg"></div>
</section>
```

thank you..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the form reset, to get back to the initial values -

```
$('#form_id').each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/hPytd/ & http://jsfiddle.net/hPytd/1/

Comment: there is no as such reset() function in jquery

Comment: Works with each function. Demo attached and reset does exist.

Comment: tried using this code and it does not work `$('form').each(function() { this.reset(); });`

Comment: works that way also - http://jsfiddle.net/hPytd/1/

Comment: not sure, but does not work for me :(

Comment: you may try to put in fiddle for demo and show what does not work. And  also revert the -ve 1 as it works perfectly.

Comment: i was not the one who down voted you, i appreciate your reply +1 for you. and thank you

Comment: ohk ... thanks much. Also where you able to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the native reset() method on the form element:

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

Comment: tried this `$('form')[0].reset();` and it does not work

Comment: It does work. find the attached demo with the each function.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the file input with html to do this,

```
 var id=$(this).attr('id');
    $(this).replaceWith("<input type='file' id='"+id+"' />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever try adding the type file to the validation,like this:

if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea' || type == 'file')

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the full scope there are multiple methods to accomplish your desired result and they are much easier than you probably think:

1. Use `<input type="reset" />` to reset your form
2. Build a [.reset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) function in jQuery:

   > ```
   > jQuery.fn.reset = function(){
   >   $(this).each (function() { this.reset(); }); 
   > }
   > ```

NOTE: Method 2 does [work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) as it is a native JavaScript function.