# Form contents do not get cleared after form submission using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a form that I am working with, and I am trying to clear it after successful submission using something like this:

```
$(':text, :password, :file, SELECT', '#create_problem').val('');
```

The id of my form is create_problem and the elements there are a text box and a check box and a text field.

The code above does nothing to help clear the form.  Is it not right?

Thanks!

To reproduce the problem: you can visit: http://www.problemio.com and login with the test account:

```
login: testuser
password: testuser
```

and try to add a problem to see that the form does not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the built in `reset()` method of the form element itself:

```
$("#MyForm").get(0).reset();
```

Comment: I just added instructions to reproduce the problem in my original question.

Comment: Add some debug.. for example `alert($("#MyForm").get(0));` and `alert($("#MyForm").get(0).reset);` - what do you get from these?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(':input, :file', '#create_problem')
     .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
     .val('')
     .removeAttr('checked')
     .removeAttr('selected');
```

Comment: After http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery/680252#680252 and N.B. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/blank-out-a-form-with-jquery/3682131#3682131