# Add delay before css adding

Tags: jquery

If the request was successful, my function performs

```
success: function () {
    $(".success-message").fadeIn(1000).delay(300).fadeOut(1000);
    $('#name').val('Ваше имя').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#phone').val('Ваш телефон').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#email').val('Электронную почту').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#url').val('Ссылку на текущий сайт').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#message').val('Ваши пожелания').css('color', '#898989');
}
```

how can I add a little delay before this part of script?

```
$('#name').val('Ваше имя').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#phone').val('Ваш телефон').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#email').val('Электронную почту').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#url').val('Ссылку на текущий сайт').css('color', '#898989');
    $('#message').val('Ваши пожелания').css('color', '#898989');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

like this

```
success: function () {
    $(".success-message").fadeIn(1000).delay(300).fadeOut(1000);

    // fire after 1 sec.
    setTimeout(function(){

       $('#name').val('Ваше имя').css('color', '#898989');
       $('#phone').val('Ваш телефон').css('color', '#898989');
       $('#email').val('Электронную почту').css('color', '#898989');
       $('#url').val('Ссылку на текущий сайт').css('color', '#898989');
       $('#message').val('Ваши пожелания').css('color', '#898989');

    }, 1000);
}
```

take a look on [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Comment: I tried this code, but I also have other function for inputs http://jsfiddle.net/9bXmy/ and when I use `setTimeout` to return default values I can't clear value of input on focus and get in inputs values from `setTimeout function` again and again.

Comment: @truslivii.lev why you are using this function to just clear the inputs? take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792320/jquery-clearing-form-inputs#answer-7792418

Comment: @truslivii.lev i slightly modify your function, take a look and use it and let me know if its working or not? http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/bNL4Y/

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/

```
 setTimeout(function(){  
   $('#name').val('Ваше имя').css('color', '#898989');
   $('#phone').val('Ваш телефон').css('color', '#898989');
   $('#email').val('Электронную почту').css('color', '#898989');
   $('#url').val('Ссылку на текущий сайт').css('color', '#898989');
   $('#message').val('Ваши пожелания').css('color', '#898989');
 }, 3000);  //do something after 3 seconds
```

Comment: I tried this code, but I also have other function for inputs http://jsfiddle.net/9bXmy/ and when I use `setTimeout` to return default values I can't clear value of input on focus and get in inputs values from `setTimeout function` again and again.