# jquery won't change input val in a form hidden with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an application using jQuery 3.2.1. It features 2 separate search forms called `#primarySearch` and `#advancedSearch`.

`#primarySearch` is always visible, but `#advancedSearch` is hidden on page load:

```
<form id="primarySearch">

</form>

<form id="advancedSearch" style="display: none;">

</form>
```

There is a button to show/hide  `#advancedSearch` like this:

```
/* Open Advanced Search */
$('#advancedSearchCta b').click(function(){
    $('#advancedSearch').toggle();
    $('#advancedSearchCta').hide();
});

/* Close Advanced Search */
$('#closeAdvancedSearch').click(function(){
    $('#advancedSearch').toggle();
    $('#advancedSearchCta').show();
});
```

This works fine.

Each form contains a number of inputs. I have implemented a button (`#resetSearchBtn`) to clear all the form inputs - effectively a "Reset Search" button:

```
 $('#resetSearchBtn').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(':input','#primarySearch, #advancedSearch')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
 });
```

This works fine **if** the `#advancedSearch` is visible. However if the user closes the advanced search - thus toggling it back to `display: none;`, it does not work. Basically, it will only reset the search if `#advancedSearch` is visible.

I can't rely on this because a user may open the advanced search, enter something, close it, and then try and do a reset. It will leave their data in `#advancedSearch`. The application is ajax based and reacts to form changes. So it basically submits the "wrong" data to the server.

Is this normal behaviour or some conflict in my app I should be looking for? What are the solutions to this?

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the same id of `resetSearchBtn`?

Comment: No, there is definitely only one. It's a button: `<button id="resetSearchBtn">`

Comment: This is very odd behaviour. The visibility of an element should have no effect on it's accessibility through code. Could you show an example of the problem in a snippet.

Comment: I agree! I don't understand it either and have never seen anything like it. It's hard to show because it's in an app being developed on a private server (I can't post a link to it). And I don't think a fiddle will help because I've no doubt it'll just work as expected on that. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: My last thought would be to check for errors in the console (assuming you haven't already) just to check if another event handler is causing an error and interfering with your logic.

Comment: It's been answered (below). It's my own stupid error!

Comment: Yeah - I missed that you were setting the `val()` on checkbox/radio buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not surprised that your code has a strange behavior. According to this code :

```
$(':input','#primarySearch, #advancedSearch')
    .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
    .val('')
    .removeAttr('checked')
    .removeAttr('selected');
```

You take every input in the form (including checkboxes and radios). You set the value to `''`. At this point, your checkboxes and radios are already dead. The you remove the attr `checked` and `selected` on everything.

First: Don't set the value of checkboxes and radios. I don't think it is what you want.

Second: `checked` and `selected` are boolean properties and must be handled with [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Third: Your code ommit every hidden elements (because of the `:hidden` selector in the `.not`). So it won't work if the form is hidden. Obviously.

Comment: As it happens I don't even need the `.not` selector at all for this part of the application. Removing it completely has solved the issue. Thanks for pointing it out, it's my own silly error!

Comment: FYI, that code came from a highly up-voted SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7792320/jquery-clearing-form-inputs :p

Comment: With a highly up-voted comment, suggesting that it won't work with checkboxes and radios

Answer (score 2):

In your `not()` filter you are specifying **not** to select elements that are hidden. Anything below the form tag with `display:none` is hidden and will not be cleared. Try being more specific in your selector. Perhaps:

```
.not(':button, :submit, :reset, form:hidden')
```