# Clear form after submission with jQuery

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery

What's the easiest way to clear this form after refresh. The way I have tried will clear the form but not submit to the database. Could someone else explain to me the best way to do this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#newsletterform").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                name: "required",
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: "Please let us know who you are.",
                email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                // do other stuff for a valid form
                $.post('newsletter.php', $("#newsletterform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });

            }

        });
    });

    </script>

</head>

<div id="content">
    <div id="newsletter-signup">
        <h1>Sign up for News, Updates, and Offers!</h1>
        <form id="newsletterform" action="" method="post">

            <fieldset>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label for="name">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" />  
                    </li>
                        <div id="results"><div>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="signup" onclick="" />         
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </fieldset>

        </form>         
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can add this to the callback from `$.post`

```
$( '#newsletterform' ).each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```

You can't just call `$( '#newsletterform' ).reset()` because `.reset()` is a form object and not a jquery object, or something to that effect.  You can read more about it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery) about half way down the page.

Comment: Thank you this worked. My mistake was I didn't realize I was placing it in the wrong location. 

Thank you for actually explaining your answer.

Comment: Have a look at the next answer before implementing this.

Comment: @IMLiviu The below answer doesn't match this question's needs.  That is for a multi-stage form.  Also, the read more link says not to use that code, but a second piece of code provided in the answer.

Answer (score 38):

You can reset your form with:

```
$("#myform")[0].reset();
```

Comment: what is the use of [0], here?

Comment: Using [0] will return you native html element not DOM.

Answer (score 15):

Better way to reset your form with jQuery is Simply `trigger` a `reset` event on your form.

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("form").trigger("reset");
    });
```

Comment: A few details to explain what you are doing here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this in your post methods callback function

```
$(':input','#myform')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

for more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Propably this would do it for you.

```
 $('input').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick reset of the form fields is possible with this jQuery reset function.
`$(selector)[0].reset();`

Answer (score -3):

Just add this to your Action file in some div or td, so that it comes with incoming XML object

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#formname").resetForm();
    </script>
```

Where "formname" is the id of form you want to edit