# Form doesn't empty fields after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Currently I'm working on a project which has a form that connects to an external database.
First I made an example, just to test if it worked. This worked fine.

But when I tried implementing it, the form doesn't empty anymore, while the example does empty the fields. My code is exactly the same, so I don't understand what's wrong. The only difference is that one file is within a jquery-mobile/phonegap folder, and the other on my htdocs.

(It does work, the only thing that it doesn't do is empty the form input fields after submitting, which is confusing for the user)

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/demo.js"></script>
    <script>
        function onBodyLoad() {     
            document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body onload="onBodyLoad()">

<div data-role="page" id="page7" class="pagina">
                <div data-role="header">
                   <h1>Name</h1>
                </div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" id="content">
                <div id="weekoverzicht">
                <form id="overzicht" method="post" onsubmit="return infoOverzicht()">
                    <label for="fruit">
                        <b>Fruit</b>
                        <input type="text" id="fruit" name="fruit">
                    </label>

                    <label for="groente">
                        <b>Groente</b>
                        <input type="text" id="groente" name="groente">
                    </label>

                    <label for="beweging">
                        <b>Beweging</b>
                        <input type="text" id="beweging" name="beweging">
                    </label>

                    <label for="duur">
                        <b>Duur</b>
                        <input type="text" id="duur" name="duur">
                    </label>

                    <input type="submit" value="Save">
                </form>
                </div>
                <div data-role="content">
                    <a data-role="button" data-transition="fade" href="#" id="button"> Data ophalen </a>
                        <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive" id="myTable">
                           <thead>
                            <tr>
                          <th data-priority="1">Fruit</th>
                              <th data-priority="1">Groente</th>
                              <th data-priority="1">Beweging</th>                             
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody data-role='listview' data-theme='c' id='mylist'></tbody>
                          </table>

                    <p id="showData"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-role="footer" style="text-align:center;" data-position="fixed">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                      <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="test.html" data-icon="plus">Test</a></li>
                        <li><a href="doel.html" data-icon="star">Doel</a></li>
                        <li><a href="score.html" data-icon="check">Score</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>                
            </div><!-- /footer -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Js file:

```
    var url = "http://example.com/";
    console.log("first page initialized");  

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url + "complex.php",
        cache: "false",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(phpData){ 
        console.log("Complex: " + phpData);

            $("#showData2").append("<b>" + phpData.comments[0].sport + "</b>");

            $.each(phpData.comments, function(index, berichtje){
                console.log(berichtje);
                $("#mylist").append( 
                    "<tr>" + 
                    "<td>" + berichtje.fruit + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + berichtje.groente + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + berichtje.beweging + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                );
            });

            $('#mylist').listview('refresh');

            },  
         error: errorHandling                   
    }); 

function infoOverzicht(){
                var data = $('form#overzicht').serialize();
                $('form#overzicht').unbind('submit');              
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://example.com/save.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    beforeSend: function() {
                    },
                        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    },
                        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }

function errorHandling(){

    console.log('er gaat iets fout');

}
```

I tried solutions like this one, but to no avail:
[Clear form after submission with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701812/clear-form-after-submission-with-jquery)

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
It's probably some stupid little thing, but I can't find it, haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I 'solved' my issue by redirecting to another page after the submitting of the form (was needed for the application, not the best solution-wise, but it works).. :)
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The trouble here is that your `success() {}` method is empty. If you don't tell it to do anything, it won't do anything.

If you did try the solution listed in [Clear form after submission with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701812/clear-form-after-submission-with-jquery) then you should show your working, so we can see what you tried to do. Right now your code does even try to do what you want so it definitely wont. :)

Googling for "Reset Form with jQuery" got me a few results. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24006921/124378) is good.

```
$("#overzicht").trigger('reset'); //jquery
document.getElementById("overzicht").reset(); //native JS
```

Pick one of those, put it in your `success() {}` and you should be fine.

Comment: I used it like this:

success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {       $("#overzicht").trigger('reset');
},
But it doesn't work. And my other html file (which has exactly the same html and jquery code) works fine...

Comment: Come on mate, help me out. "Does not work" is vague. Do you get a PHP error? Does the callback DEFINITELY fire? Did you do any debugging, like put a console.log() in the success? Did the network request fail? Can jQuery find $('#overzicht') properly? Is the reset event firing?

Answer (score 0):

Can also maybe try:

```
$('form#overzicht input').val('');
```