# How to reset the form data when form submit on click of button

Tags: php, ajax, form-submit

What should be the code here if the user clicks the back button after submitting form, data must be reset.

Here is my code so far:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){

  } else{

  }

});
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701812/clear-form-after-submission-with-jquery)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3786694/6521116 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/16452699/6521116

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form submit after response with add this line and form id

```
document.getElementById("formID").reset();
```

Comment: sir document.getElementById("client").reset(); not working in chrome.In firefox its working

Answer (score 1):

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
//YOUR ACTION GOES HERE
$('#YOURFORMID')[0].reset();
  } else{

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(':input','#myform')
 .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
 .val('')
 .removeAttr('checked')
 .removeAttr('selected');
```

Or

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```