# reset ajax form after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, reset

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'text'     : $('input[name=text]').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type   : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url   : 'class/sendchat.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data   : formData, // our data object
            dataType  : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
            encode   : true
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="contact-forms" name="contact-form" action="#">
    <input name="text" type="text" placeholder="متن پیام" style="width: 90%; float: right;">
    <a class="write-link send" style="width: 10%; float: left;" onclick="submitForm()"></a>
    <input type="submit" class="hide">
</form>
```

I want reset my from after submit.

how can i reset input[name=text] after submit?

Comment: add  `$('input[name=text]').val('')` at the success property of the ajax call like `success: function(data){ $('input[name=text]').val('')}`

Comment: Back to the basics. `form.reset()`

Comment: if you want to reset the entire form then use `form.reset()` or `$("#contact-forms")[0].reset()`

Comment: Here is a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701812/clear-form-after-submission-with-jquery

Comment: This question had the most upvotes and stars within 6 minutes than I have ever seen... people don't know how to research this?

Comment: @KevinB hmm correct typo

Comment: $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text]").val("");