# Reset HTML form after submit

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const scriptURL = 'URL'
const form = document.forms['myform']

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  fetch(scriptURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: new FormData(form)
    })
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
});
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
      <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

How can I reset my form after handling form submission?

Here's what I am doing currently:

```
 form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                          e.preventDefault()
                          fetch(scriptURL, { method: 'POST', body: new FormData(form)})
                          .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
                          .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
                          })
                         $('#myform').reset(); // attempt to reset the form
```

I searched for similar threads and tried `$('#myform').reset();` 
Clearly it's not working, 
I am new to Javascript if anyone can point me where to learn this form related topics then it will be great

EDIT: Form source

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
            </form>
```

I tried the following suggestions:

```
  $('#myform').val(''); // not responding
  $('#myform')[0].reset // not responding
  $('#myform').reset(); // not responding
  $('#myform').get(0).reset(); // not responding

  $('#myform').find("input:not([type="submit"), textarea").val(""); // resetting the whole page with performing submission task

  $('#myform')[0].reset() // not responding
  document.forms['myform'].val(""); // not responding
  document.getElementById('#myform').reset() // not responding
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML form code!

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701812/clear-form-after-submission-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear form fields with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364289/clear-form-fields-with-jquery)

Comment: Probably not enough jQuery.

Comment: @HarishST just added, please check the updated question

Comment: Your form does not have the id myform, so you can not select it by it. $('[name="myform"]').get(0).reset();

Comment: As @Lain said, # is for selecting *id* not *name* try adding an id="myform" and check again!

Comment: @HarishST just added the ID, please check the updated question

Comment: Shouldn't the call to reset be inside the function that handles the submit event?

Comment: What about the semicolumn after addEventListener() ? And you have added Jquery script to your page?

Comment: @HarishST Please check my recent update

Comment: Since you declare form and use it inside your listener anyway, cant you just do form.reset()? Works fine for me if I rebuild your code.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$('#myform').find("input:not([type="submit"), textarea").val("");
```

It will clear all data of your form. but if you have prefilled value, you should use this code: `document.getElementById('myform').reset()`

> Note: Use 'myform' as your form id attribute. ex: `<form name="myform"
>   id="myform">`

Comment: Is emptying all values really the same as reseting a form? What about prefilled values?

Comment: @Delowar just tried your suggestion, seems like it's resetting the whole page instead of just form

Comment: if you have prefilled value, you should use this code: document.getElementById('myform').reset();

Answer (score 3):

You need to get actual form rather than jQuery object:

```
$('#myform').get(0).reset();
```

Answer (score 3):

For the javascript to know what form to reset, you need to add id to the form, not just a name. Try,

```
<form name="myform" id="myform">
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note that a form reset will bring it to its original state as it was rendered. If you had prepopulated fields, those fields will get that value again. Besides that, there are 2 things you need to fix:

- `$('#myform')` needs an `id="myform"` in the HTML to get the form as jQuery object.
- `reset()` only works on the HTML form object, not on a jQuery object. Either change your call to `$('#myform')[0].reset()` or to `document.getElementById('myform').reset()`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to clear your form is to set the value to "empty" like so:

```
$('#myForm').val('');
```

Then the form input has no value in it!

```js
$('#myBtn').click(function () {
  $('#myForm').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" value="hello world" id="myForm">

<button id="myBtn">myBtn</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('#myform').reset() // not responding
```

You were almost there.. `getElementByID` so you can omit # in ('#myform')

This would work if you used `document.getElementById('myform').reset();`

For some reason `reset()` does not work with jquery only with pure JS.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is not required for everything

```
<form action='server-script.cgi' onsubmit='this.submit();this.reset();return false;'>
  <blah>...</blah>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the real form `$('#myForm')[0].reset()`
2. You need to add an id tag to your form
   `<form id="myForm">`

If you just used plain js, you could go with `document.getElementById('myForm').reset()` but still, add an id tag to your form

Edit: corrections pointed out in the comment

Comment: Even with the id your selector seems wrong to me. Also use .get(0). If you really feel the urge to use jquery atleast be consistent in it.

Comment: Could you elaborate what event you mean?

Comment: They didn't say event ;-). Your jQuery statement is not fully correct. The `#` is missing in the selector and you should call `reset()` as a function. There's nothing wrong using `[0]` instead of `get(0)`: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("myform").addEventListener('submit',reset_form);

function reset_form(event) {
  //Your code goes here
  document.getElementById("myform").reset();
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" id="myform">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
      <input name="email" id="myform" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Subscribe</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Are you looking for this ? And do your coding inside the function! 
Alternatively, If you don't want the form to submit, you can use the button *type="button"* instead of "submit" also.

Answer (score 0):

Since `form` is declared and resused in the listener anyway, could just call a reset on it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                const scriptURL = 'URL';
                const form = document.forms['myform'];

                form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
                    e.preventDefault()

                    fetch(scriptURL, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        body: new FormData(form)
                    })
                    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
                    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message));

                    form.reset() //Reset the form
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="myform">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                    <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Subscribe</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#yourInputID').val('');
```

this will reset reset the selected input by its Id.

Answer (score 0):

**Reason**

while using fetch() for the data is already delivered and you only get response object back from server. the reset() inside fetch.then() won't execute.

**Workaround**

one of the way to make things work is , instead of getting form data inside fetch , you should collect data before that & saved it somewhere and reset the form.

**Code**

```
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const options = {
     method: 'POST',
     body: new FormData(form),
  }

  form.reset();

  fetch(scriptURL, options)
    .then(response => console.log('Success!', response))
    .catch(error => console.error('Error!', error.message))
  });
```