# Restoring selects after submit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms, select, each

THis is how i am trying (no firebug errors) to restore each select of my form to its first option value

```
/* $(this) is the form */
$(this).find('input[type="text"],textarea').val(''); /* This works */
$(this).find("select").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this,"option:first").val());  /* this doesnt do anything */
});
```

what am i doing wroing?

-edit-

just found out.. this works, why not with the comma?

```
$(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
$(this).find("select").change();
```

This will automatically set the first option value as default.

If you use you code you need:

```
$(this).find("select").each(function(){

    $(this).val($("option:first", this ).val());  /* this doesnt do anything */

                                   ^--- this will places here

});
```

Your `$(this, "option:first")` not worked because you code is searching a `select` within a `option`, but it should search `option` within `search`.

One format of jquery selector is

```
$(target, context);
```

Comment: sweet! easier than i thought! but still curious why selecting with the 'comma,' doesn't work