# How to reset form validation after server side validation error?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have a from, in which users will fill a number that shall be unique, otherwise rails will respond on an error : "has already been taken"

I am using `validates_uniqueness_of` at the model, so every thing is fine.

The problem is that when the error message "has already been taken" appears, I can no more submit the form, even if I cleared the text box, it seems that the form validator get stuck ..

I tried `$("#class_room_form").validate().resetForm();` but, it didn't work, I still can't submit the form ..

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you looked through this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery

Comment: I tried the best answer, it will just reset fields, the form still can't be submitted ..

Comment: If you clear the form, what about doing a self-redirect? In essense, send them back to the same page? Also, are you using post?