# How to reset a form programmatically?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to reset a form in a JQuery click event function. How to do that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At it's simplest: `$("form-selector-here")[0].reset()` but also see: [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery/680252)

Note that jQuery isn't necessary for this at all, as `$(selector)[0]` obtains the original DOM element. You could also say `document.getElementById("myFormId").reset()`.

```
​$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#form1")[0].reset();

    // OR
    document.getElementById("form1").reset();
});​​​
```

Comment: The accepted answer to that question is just setting the input fields to blank, but a true reset sets all input fields to their original value.

Comment: I think the answers to that question collectively cover the important scenarios, though?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$("#formid")[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#FormID').each (function(){
this.reset();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#resetForm').click(function(){
        $('form input[type=text]').val('');});
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ntcg3/25/)

Answer (score 0):

add this at the end of the form:

```
<div style="display='none';" ><input type="reset" id="rst_form"></div>
```

and try this:

```
$('#rst_form').click()
```