# Reset the form after element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is such a HTML code:

```
<div class="addMore"></div>
<div class="adProfInner">
   <div class="formAdd"><form></form></div>
</div>
```

By clicking on the addMore need to reset the form to the container `formAdd`

Here is that code did not work:

```
$(this).next('.adProfInner').find('form').trigger('reset');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset a form programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313312/how-to-reset-a-form-programmatically)

Answer (score 2):

Can try using `reset()`. Example:

```
$('.addMore').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.adProfInner').find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

Comment: Does not work, only input text was cleared. But select lists does not with a attribute `selected`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this method.

```
$('.addMore').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.adProfInner').find('form').reset();
});
```

or

```
<div class="addMore"></div>
<div class="adProfInner">
   <div class="formAdd"><form id='my_form'></form></div>
</div>
```

script here

```
 $('.addMore').click(function(){
        $('#my_form').reset();
    });
```

Comment: If use `$('#my_form').reset();` I get error: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`