# How can I reset form data that is at before current page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have created one JSP page to insert user information and to show inserted info:

To get my insert data page I have a link eg: ***mysite/insertInfo***

First accept user information and validate them. If valid submit form.Else when validation errors has occured , redirect to same page and without losing any form datas. At servlet (or controller class) save data and redirect to same page. I used redirecting with jQuery as like below:

```
url = baseURL + "/saveUserInfo";
params = {};
params.name = $(".txtname').val();
params.email = $('.txtemail').val();
ajax(url, params, false, function(data) {
    $('.form').empty();
    if (data) {
        // SHOW SUCCESS INFO
        html = [];
        html.push("<div>Success</div>");
        $('. form').append(html.join(''));
    }
});
```

Second, I will show these were inserted before. Yes, it was simple and fine.

My problems is that when the user go to page  ***mysite/insertInfo***
 again, there has a form with inserted data. No, I don't want to see them again. I don't want to redirect to another page eg: success.jsp . I only want to use one JSP file. As description of [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery), I tested with it.

Like `$('#myform').trigger("reset");` before submitting this form. It is fine and reset. But when I reached successful page and go back insert form page via link, I see form with previous inserted data. How to handle it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. I think my browser may cached it but I am not sure.

Comment: Why are you not using $.ajax{success:function(){});

Answer (score 1):

When you have saved the data successfully add this to clear each input field

```
$('form input').val("");
```

Comment: I assume that will similar with $('#myform').trigger("reset"); Did you mean my JSP should have boolean variable to check clear form data. Sorry for my forget to display , when validation was invalid , redirect to same page and without losing any form datas.

Answer (score 0):

Now , my problem was fined , By using sessionStorage from  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp . It is really fine by adding following scripts..

> ```
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>         function insert_previous_datas() {
>             var name = sessionStorage.getItem("name");
>             if (name) {
>                 $('#inputName').val(name);
>             }
>             var email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
>             if (email){
>                 $('#inputEmail').val(email);
>             }
>         }
>         window.onload = function() {
>             var isForReview = sessionStorage.getItem("forReview"); 
>             if (isForReview) {
>                 insert_previous_datas();
>                 sessionStorage.removeItem("forReview");
>             }
>             var isForValidate  = sessionStorage.getItem("forValidate");
>             if (isForValidate) {
>                 insert_previous_datas();
>                 var errorMsgName = sessionStorage.getItem("errorMsgName");
>                 if (errorMsgName) {
>                     $('#errorMsgName').addClass("error");
>                     $('#errorMsgName').text(errorMsgName);
>                 }
>                 var errorMsgEmail = sessionStorage.getItem("errorMsgEmail");
>                 if (errorMsgEmail) {
>                     $('#errorMsgEmail').addClass("error");
>                     $('#errorMsgEmail').text(errorMsgEmail);
>                 }
>                 sessionStorage.removeItem("forValidate");
>             }
>         }
>     </script>
> ```