# First form of nested form tags not responding to css display:none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have nested form tags like this

```
<form>
    <h5>Main Form</h5>
    <input type="text" />

    <!-- Don't Show This Form -->
    <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>

    <!-- Don't Show This Form -->
    <form style="display:none">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="text" />
    </form>

</form>
```

The problem is the first form displaying although It's display none **css inline**

See the code in action http://jsfiddle.net/fZMKB/

**I know I know, nested forms is against the rules But I have to use it this way for this reason**

I need to reset bunch of ***inputs and form elements*** before jQuery event and I'm using this code

```
    $('form').get(0).reset();
```

From this my earlier question [How to reset forms elements (input,select,textarea,etc.) on events using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364393/how-to-reset-forms-elements-input-select-textarea-etc-on-events-using-jquery)

So the only reason I use form tag is I need to reset inputs and textarea, etc..

Comment: You can;t have nested form tags.

Comment: "I know I know, nested forms is against the rules" — Yes it is, and it doesn't work, so find a different way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I nest form tags in other form tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519485/can-i-nest-form-tags-in-other-form-tags)

Comment: @jim I like the way you think. But unfortunately you can't have nested `form`

Comment: Thanx @RakeshJuyal, I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery to reset my form elements instead of `$('form').get(0).reset();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's never a good reason to have nested forms. Instead, use proper HTML syntax and adjust your jQuery code accordingly. Here's some valid HTML markup:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <h5>Main Form</h5>
  <input type="text">
  <div class="one" style="display:none">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="two" style="display:none">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</form>
```

Let's say you want to reset all text inputs, checkboxes, radio buttons, and select menus in the first subsection. This would only take two simple lines of jQuery:

```
$(".one input, .one select").val("");
$(".one textarea").html("");
```

If you want to restore default values, you should store the values in the HTML markup using the `data` attribute. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pgNrF/3/

Comment: Unfortunately I need the out to be form to reset any inputs inside it using `$('form').get(0).reset();` any way around it to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364393/how-to-reset-forms-elements-input-select-textarea-etc-on-events-using-jquery

Comment: Why do the inner forms even exist? Will they be submitted separately to a different endpoint on the server? If not, you can get rid of them.

Comment: I use the inputs and textareas and other form elements to collect entries from the user and reusing with javascript to generate a bigger content and at the end I send it to the server, and sometimes I need to reset these form elements

Comment: Programming requires adhering to a strict set of rules. When you deviate from the rules, unexpected things will happen. There are other ways to clear form fields besides `reset()`. For example, you can do `$("input").val("")`. Fix the syntax first, then address the problem.

Comment: I have to go back to reset step :(, So any suggestion for effective way to reset inputs and textareas and radios and checkboxes and options (dropdown)?, and Thank you for your time :)

Comment: I remembered why I did not use this method http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/pgNrF/2/ check this, some inputs have default values and checkboxs and radios not reseting,, Is there any jQuery plugin function out there to do the reset trick without remove anything??

Comment: I got very effective function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery If anyone facing the same issue :)

Answer (score 0):

No, nested forms are forbidden.

This is expressed in the HTML 4.01 DTDs as:

```
<!ELEMENT FORM - - (%block;|SCRIPT)+ -(FORM) -- interactive form -->
```

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

A FORM has a mandatory start tag, mandatory end tag and can contain anything in %block or SCRIPT, except other FORMs.

XML DTDs aren't as expressive as SGML DTDs so in XHTML this rule is specified only in the human readable text of the specification:

form must not contain other form elements.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions

HTML 5 isn't an SGML application and doesn't have an official machine readable description of the language. It also expresses this rule in text:

Content model:

Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element

**[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519485/can-i-nest-form-tags-in-other-form-tags)**

Comment: What solution do you suggest to go around it??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have nested forms in HTML , you can have different forms but not nested

See this  http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element

```
Content model
Flow content, but with no form element descendants.
```