# Clone form input and clear value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an upload form. It's working well so far and i'm trying to sort out a couple of bugs that I dislike.

The line that I seem to be having trouble with is

```
$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
```

When cloning the form, it clones the div and replaces the value with nothing leaving a blank form, this works well, if I were to delete that line I would get the previous form's value, so it would be nice for a blank form to show.

The issue i'm having is when you delete a form all the forms values delete, What I want is when you delete a form, leave the value alone for the other forms.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d77pd/1/ or see code below

**HTML**

```
<button class="clone">Add an Image</button>
<div id="upload_image_sets">
    <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
        <input type="text" id="upload_image_link_1" class="image" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="' . $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] . '" />
        <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function updateClonedInput(index, element) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_image_sets").attr("id", "clonedInput" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "cs_product_menu_img_src_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_img_src_" + index + "_button");
    displayRemove();
}

function displayRemove() {
    if ($('.clonedInput').length === 1) {
        $('.remove').hide();
    } else {
        $('.remove').show();
    }
}
displayRemove();

$(document).on("click", ".clone", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).closest('.clonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.clonedInput').clone() : $(".clonedInput:last").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);
});
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    $(".clonedInput").each(function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    })
});
```

Clone the form a few times, if you delete any form apart form the 1st one with the content, you'll notice the first form's content deletes, I want this left alone.

Comment: Is there a specific requirement for incrementing `id` attributes on every clone? I only ask because the cloning, appending and clearing values could be performed with a lot less code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First approach:**
call `$(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");` after calling `updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);` from add function.

**[Working Demo First approach:](http://jsfiddle.net/d77pd/4/)**

**Second Approach:**

I have modified some code. pass one more bool argument in function `updateClonedInput`.which will be set true when added and set false when dom is removed.This will prevent the value getting replaced on remove function:

```
  function updateClonedInput(index, element,param) {
    $(element).appendTo("#upload_image_sets").attr("id", "clonedInput" +  index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("id", "cs_product_menu_img_src_" + index);
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("name", "hero_options[upload_image_link_" + index + "]");
if(param)
    $(element).find(">:first-child").attr("value", "");
    $(element).find(">:first-child").next().attr("id", "cs_product_menu_img_src_" + index + "_button");
    displayRemove();
}

function displayRemove() {
if($('.clonedInput').length === 1) {
    $('.remove').hide();
} else {
    $('.remove').show();
}
 }
 displayRemove();

$(document).on("click", ".clone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(this).closest('.clonedInput').length ? $(this).closest('.clonedInput').clone() : $(".clonedInput:last").clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input,true);    
});
$(document).on("click", ".remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement,false);
    })
});
```

**[Working Demo Second Approach](http://jsfiddle.net/d77pd/3/)**

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why.

Comment: Neither demo works for me. A value added to a clone row is copied to the next clone.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution that creates a blank clone from the first element once, then uses this every time a new row is required. It also uses CSS to hide/show the **Remove** button based on the fact that you only need **Remove** buttons on all rows unless it's the only child.

*Disclaimer: I have removed the `id` manipulation as I am unsure if you really need it. I can update if necessary.*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2nSeL/3/)

**HTML**

```
<button class="clone">Add an Image</button>
<div id="upload_image_sets">
    <div class="clonedInput">
        <input type="text" class="image" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="an initial value" />
        <input class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
        <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clonedInput .remove {
    display:inline-block;
}

.clonedInput:only-child .remove {
    display:none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val('');
    $form.find('input:radio, input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
}

var $blankClone = $('.clonedInput').clone();
resetForm($blankClone);

$(document).on('click', '.clone', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $blankClone.clone().appendTo('#upload_image_sets');
});

$('#upload_image_sets').on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.clonedInput').remove();
});
```

`resetForm()` borrowed from [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)

Comment: Even remove button does not get appended to each add.