# ajax command with Reset button

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

i have 6 textfields, if we user write something, if he felt written something wrong and want to reset page, I dont want to reload that page again just want to reset those fields as blank through ajax command, can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/680241/1700321)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need AJAX or even JavaScript, just use the [`<s:reset/>`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/reset.html) tag / button.

Comment: can u tell me how to use it here?<label class="fulllabel">Title<font color="red">*</font>:</label><s:select list="titleList" tabindex="3" cssClass="fullcontrol"
      name="users.title"></s:select>

Comment: Add <s:reset /> as the last tag in your form. You can specify a theme and most of the other normal UI tag parameters to help make sure that the button appears uniformly in your input form.