# How to reset email input type selector in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, email

So I've just come across this answer:
[Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery) But this doesn't mention how to reset the email input type?

I've tried `currentForm.find(':input:email').val('');`, but this isn't recognised as a selector. What's the correct way to reset all inputs of type email on a form?

I'm using a html element of type email:

```
<input placeholder="Email" type="email" name="email" required>
```

So this must be possible without having to reset it explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`type` is an attribute, so you should use an attribute selector:

```
$(":input[type=email]", currentForm).val("");
```