# how to remove a file from an input after submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form , there is an input type file , that element has a button with a on click event calling a function to upload the file (image), after that user has filled all his data hit the button validate ,
i want to clear the input type file once the user has clicked upload file and file has been uploaded , because what happening is that file to be uploaded to the server it takes time when the user hit upload file and also when he clicks validate button because it's passing in http request as an element of the form so what i want is to remove the file from the input once it is uploaded , this is my code i tested different scenarios none of them has worked.

```
<div>
    <input type='file' name='img1' id='img1'>
    <input type="button" value="upload" onclick="uploadFile()">
  <progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress>
</div>
```

js

```
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);

}
function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("img1").files[0];
    var e = document.getElementById("img1");
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("img1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", 'distination');
    ajax.send(formdata);
    formdata.delete("img1");
    formdata = '';
    _("img1").files[0] = '';

    e.value ='';
    $('#img1').val('');
    $('#img1')[0].reset();
}
```

the action of the form is PHP_SELF

Comment: remove `name` attribute from `input type='file'`

Comment: Is this code even successfully uploading the file?

Comment: file is uploading with upload button , not with button of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this by searching StackOverflow for what you are specifically trying to do:

```
function resetForm($form) {
    $form.find('input:file').val('');
}
// to call, use:
resetForm($('#myform'));
```

This solution was derived entirely from [Resetting a multi-stage form with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680241/resetting-a-multi-stage-form-with-jquery)

Example usage when you submit the form would be:

```
$('#validateButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    resetForm($('#myform'));
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Where `#validateButton` and `#myform` should be replaced with the actual names of your DOM elements.

Comment: no it didnt wok file still passing with data of the form

Comment: I updated my answer. replace validateButton with the actually DOM element button ID that triggers on click.

Comment: thanks for your help Alexander but i m sorry it didn t work

Comment: Updated the solution again, please let me know if it helps.